# Is Mission Control an addition to Exposé & Spaces UI or a replacement?

Tags: macos, spaces, expose, mission-control

Lion has Mission Control that combines features from both Exposé and Spaces. Do the old Exposé and Spaces UIs still exist in Lion or does Mission Control replace them?

I've heard mixed rumors about whether Spaces/Exposé exists or not; and all the YouTube et al. videos/reports concentrate on featuring the Mission Control but won't tell straight if it is an *addition* or a *replacement*.

I understand, though, there are **s**paces—called desktops—on the top of the Mission Control UI.
There definitely are spaces, but is there Spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mission Control replaces them.

All the things that you used to be able to do in expose and spaces should be in Mission Control as well (Well... Not really, you can't have spaces arranged in two dimensional space anymore).

But no, there's no more Spaces or Expose anymore. Yes it's called desktop now.

Comment: "All the things you used to be able to do...". The list is *way* longer than that.

Comment: Another thing you can't do is open Spaces and drag windows between them. Instead, you can go to a certain space, *then* go to Mission Control, and then drag windows from *that* space to *other* spaces, but you can't just freely grab a window from any space and move it to another one. It's such a shame.

Comment: It replaces them, but with different functionality, not more. *Many* happy Spaces/Expose users are left cold by Mission Control.